# How to change status of the object automatically?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, vuejs3

I am working on a project, aim of the project is that user creates announcement and I need to change `is_active` status to `False` automatically after 30 days so announcement be active 30 days but I have no idea how to do that, I am using Django Rest Framework and VueJs.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have a task system set up, something like [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Then have a task that runs daily getting announcement objects with a created date of greater than 30 days.

Once you have those objects you can set the is_active status to False.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom command for django which you can run with crontab every day.
With this command you select everything with a creation-date greater than 30 days

Answer (score 0):

This is not all this is only Little help......

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_months(sourcedate, months):
    month = sourcedate.month - 1 + months
    year = sourcedate.year + month // 12
    month = month % 12 + 1
    day = min(sourcedate.day, calendar.monthrange(year,month)[1])
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)
```